# Como bloquear o acesso do internet explorer?

Tags: htaccess

Como eu posso bloquear meu site de ser acessado pelo iternet explorer via .htaccess? Eu já tentei códigos como:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MSIE [6-8]" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.com/ie [R=301,L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} *MSIE*
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://example.com/ie/ [L]
RewriteRule  ^/$ http://example.com/index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Mas não funcionou, alguém sabe algum outro código que funcione?

Answer (score 0):

Usa assim:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MSIE [6-8]" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.com/ie [R=301,L]
```

Ele vai redirecionar para http://mysite.com/ie, onde você pode colocar alguma mensagem informando o usuário.
Deixa só essa parte, na parte "MSIE [6-8]" é a versão do IE.

Comment: Testei aqui no XAMPP deu Internal Server Error, se coloco com `MSIE [10-12]` não da o erro, mas também não "bloqueia".

Comment: Verifica no arquivo de configuração do apache se a variável AllowOverride  está ALL, e no lugar de `"MSIE [6-8]" [NC]` coloca `*MSIE*`

Comment: Sim, na opção `<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">` está como `AllowOverride All`

Comment: kkkk agora o Chrome está redirecionando, mas o IE continua na mesma. :P

Comment: Eu utilizei esse código e não funcionou :(.